# Trying to access variable from outside foreach loop

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, loops

The application I am building allows a user to upload a .csv file, which will ultimately fill in fields of an existing SQL table where the Ids match. First, I am using LinqToCsv and a foreach loop to import the .csv into a temporary table. Then I have another foreach loop where I am trying to loop the rows from the temporary table into an existing table where the Ids match.

**Controller Action to complete this process:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadValidationTable(HttpPostedFileBase csvFile)
{
    var inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
    {
        SeparatorChar = ',',
        FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
    };
    var cc = new CsvContext();
    var filePath = uploadFile(csvFile.InputStream);
    var model = cc.Read<Credit>(filePath, inputFileDescription);

    try
    {
        var entity = new TestEntities();
        var tc = new TemporaryCsvUpload();
        foreach (var item in model)
        {

            tc.Id = item.Id;
            tc.CreditInvoiceAmount = item.CreditInvoiceAmount;
            tc.CreditInvoiceDate = item.CreditInvoiceDate;
            tc.CreditInvoiceNumber = item.CreditInvoiceNumber;
            tc.CreditDeniedDate = item.CreditDeniedDate;
            tc.CreditDeniedReasonId = item.CreditDeniedReasonId;
            tc.CreditDeniedNotes = item.CreditDeniedNotes;
            entity.TemporaryCsvUploads.Add(tc);
        }

        var idMatches = entity.Authorizations.ToList().Where(x => x.Id == tc.Id);

        foreach (var number in idMatches)
        {
            number.CreditInvoiceDate = tc.CreditInvoiceDate;
            number.CreditInvoiceNumber = tc.CreditInvoiceNumber;
            number.CreditInvoiceAmount = tc.CreditInvoiceAmount;
            number.CreditDeniedDate = tc.CreditDeniedDate;
            number.CreditDeniedReasonId = tc.CreditDeniedReasonId;
            number.CreditDeniedNotes = tc.CreditDeniedNotes;
        }
        entity.SaveChanges();
        entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE TemporaryCsvUpload");

        TempData["Success"] = "Updated Successfully";

    }
    catch (LINQtoCSVException)
    {
        TempData["Error"] = "Upload Error: Ensure you have the correct header fields and that the file is of .csv format.";
    }

    return View("Upload");
}
```

The issue in the above code is that `tc` is inside the first loop, but the matches are defined after the loop with `var idMatches = entity.Authorizations.ToList().Where(x => x.Id == tc.Id);`, so I am only getting the last item of the first loop.

So I would need to put `var idMatches = entity.Authorizations.ToList().Where(x => x.Id == tc.Id);` in the first loop, but then I can't access it in the second. If I nest the second loop then it is way to slow. Is there any way I could put the above statement in the first loop and still access it. Or any other ideas to accomplish the same thing? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want duplicates for rows where ID matches or just a single row for each unique ID?

Comment: Since row for each unique id

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using multiple loops, keep track of processed IDs as you go and then exclude any duplicates.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadValidationTable(HttpPostedFileBase csvFile)
{
    var inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
    {
        SeparatorChar = ',',
        FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
    };
    var cc = new CsvContext();
    var filePath = uploadFile(csvFile.InputStream);
    var model = cc.Read<Credit>(filePath, inputFileDescription);

    try
    {
        var entity = new TestEntities();
        var tcIdFound = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (var item in model)
        {
                        if (tcIdFound.Contains(item.Id)) 
                        {
                            continue;
                        }                   

            var tc = new TemporaryCsvUpload();
            tc.Id = item.Id;
            tc.CreditInvoiceAmount = item.CreditInvoiceAmount;
            tc.CreditInvoiceDate = item.CreditInvoiceDate;
            tc.CreditInvoiceNumber = item.CreditInvoiceNumber;
            tc.CreditDeniedDate = item.CreditDeniedDate;
            tc.CreditDeniedReasonId = item.CreditDeniedReasonId;
            tc.CreditDeniedNotes = item.CreditDeniedNotes;

            entity.TemporaryCsvUploads.Add(tc);
        }

        entity.SaveChanges();
        entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE TemporaryCsvUpload");

        TempData["Success"] = "Updated Successfully";

    }
    catch (LINQtoCSVException)
    {
        TempData["Error"] = "Upload Error: Ensure you have the correct header fields and that the file is of .csv format.";
    }

    return View("Upload");
}
```

If you want to make sure you get the last value for any duplicate ids, then store each `TemporaryCsvUpload` record in a dictionary instead of using only a `HashSet`. Same basic idea though.

Comment: Looks great, I should've noted that the Ids are unique varchars though.

Comment: @CavanFlynn, ok, that should only affect the type declaration for the `HashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `idMatches` before the first loop, but don't instantiate it or set its value to `null`. Then you'll be able to use it inside both loops. After moving the declaration before the first loop, you'll still end up having the values from the last iteration using a simple `Where`. You'll need to concatenate the already existing list with results for the current iteration.